# Using the comparison test to determine if a series converges

Tags: calculus, analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to make sure I am correctly understanding the intuition behind the comparison theorem. Suppose I'm given the following integral:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\arctan{x}}{2+e^x}$$ First, I notice that $\arctan{x}$ lies between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $0\leq x<\infty$. From this I have that $\arctan{x}<\frac{\pi}{2}$, such that $$\frac{\arctan{x}}{2+e^x}<\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{2+e^x}\bigg)=\frac{\pi}{4+2e^x}.$$ I can make this expression on the right even bigger by making the denominator smaller. That is, we have the following inequality:

$$\frac{\arctan{x}}{2+e^x}<\frac{\pi}{4+2e^x}<\frac{\pi}{2e^x}.$$ It remains to investigate the convergence of $$\frac{\pi}{2e^x}.$$ We have that $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\pi}{2e^x}=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}=\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg(\lim_{t\to\infty}-e^{-x}\bigg|_0^t\bigg)=\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg(\lim_{t\to\infty}-e^{-t}+1\bigg).$$ The limit is convergent, and because our upper bound converges, so too must our original function by the comparison test. Does this seem like a good way of going about solving such problems?

Comment: You should also point out the fact that the function is also non-negative over the entire interval.  $-1<\frac{\pi}{2e^x}$ for all $x$ as well but $\int\limits_0^\infty -1dx$ doesn't converge.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ah, I see. This makes sense. I had forgotten about that condition. Otherwise, does it seem okay?

Comment: When you evaluate $-\mathrm{e}^{-x}$ at the lower bound $x=0$, you should get $1$ instead of $\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}}$. Apart from that, everything looks fine. I do not think that there is a better approach to this problem.

Comment: It is a valid method. If $F(x)$ is non-negative and increasing for $x\geq 0$ (i.e. $x'>x\geq 0\implies F(x')\geq F(x)\geq 0$)... and if there exists $M\in \Bbb R^+$ such that $\forall x\geq 0\;( F(x)\leq M),$ then $\lim_{x\to \infty}F(x)$ exists in $\Bbb R.$.... For example if  $F(x)=\int_0^x(\arctan y)(2+e^y)^{-1}dy.$

Comment: With regard to my prior comment we  can weaken the conditions on $F$ to "if  $F(x)$ is  increasing on $ [k,\infty)$ for some $k\in \Bbb R^+,$ (and  $\sup_{x\geq 
 k}F(x) \leq M<\infty)$ "  because what $F(x)$ is when $x<k$ has no effect on whether $\lim_{x\to \infty}F(x)$ exists And the condition  that $F$ is non-negative is unnecessary